# How to use raw_input to control pwm

Tags: python, pygame, raw-input, pwm

I'm trying to use the `raw_input` function to type in a letter such as `l` or `r` and it will be a certain pwm value like `0.4` or `1.6`. Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.cleanup()

enable_pin = 18
coil_A_1_pin = 27
coil_A_2_pin = 17
coil_B_1_pin = 23
coil_B_2_pin = 24
coil_A_x1_pin = 22
coil_A_x2_pin = 5
coil_B_x1_pin = 6
coil_B_x2_pin = 13

s = 12
GPIO.setup(enable_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_x1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_x2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_x1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_x2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(s, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(enable_pin, 1)

def forward(delay, steps):  
  for i in range(0, steps):
    setStep(1, 1, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0, 1, 1, 0)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0, 0, 1, 1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(1, 0, 0, 1)
    time.sleep(delay)

def backwards(delay, steps):  
  for i in range(0, steps):
    setStep(1, 0, 0, 1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0, 0, 1, 1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(0, 1, 1, 0)
    time.sleep(delay)
    setStep(1, 1, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(delay)


def setStep(w1, w2, w3, w4):
  GPIO.output(coil_A_1_pin, w1)
  GPIO.output(coil_A_x1_pin, w1)
  GPIO.output(coil_A_2_pin, w2)
  GPIO.output(coil_A_x2_pin, w2)
  GPIO.output(coil_B_1_pin, w3)
  GPIO.output(coil_B_x1_pin, w3)
  GPIO.output(coil_B_2_pin, w4)
  GPIO.output(coil_B_x2_pin, w4)


p = GPIO.PWM(s,7.5) 


try:
  while True:
    l = 0.3
    r = 1.7
    n = 1.1
    pos = raw_input("Left(l), right(r) or neutral(n)? ")
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(float(pos))
    delay = raw_input("Delay between steps (milliseconds)? ")
    steps = raw_input("How many steps forward? ")
    forward(int(delay) / 1000.0, int(steps))
    steps = raw_input("How many steps backwards? ")
    backwards(int(delay) / 1000.0, int(steps))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

I also have another program that does this with `pygame` but I can't figure out how to use that over ssh on a dev mode chromebook so I ditched that. Also don't mind all the `def`s and other things for my stepper motor that I'm also running. The stepper motor works fine because I'm inputting numerals directly and not variables but I can't figure out how to make it work with variables. Also it would be awesome if someone showed me how to run pygame over ssh on a chromebook which would make it a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

For the variable `pos` you should rather use `input` instead of `raw_input`. 
 Basically `s = input('Say: ')` does the same thing as

```
s = eval( raw_input('Say: ') )
```

i.e. the given input string will be *evaluated*. Then you won't even need to make a float of it.

Comment: OK, I'll try it and get back to you.